# Assign property to array of object

Tags: php

I try to assign the value to my array of object

```
$models = [new Form()];

    for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
        $models[$i]->title = $i;
    }
```

when I try I got error

```
Creating default object from empty value
```

So How can I assign the value more than `$models[0]`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this by

```
$models = [];

for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
    $models[$i] = new Form();
    $models[$i]->title = $i;
}
```

Thanks @castis.